# How to get a link to an old question that was probably deleted for no answer/no votes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, specific-question

I'd solved a scripting problem and included it as part of a question here a few years ago. I don't see the question and I'm guessing it was deleted for no answers/no activity or similar. I've searched for the script or blend everywhere on my computer and can't find any trace of it.

- old = circa 2016,
- possibly contains some of: interpolate, interpolation, bend, extrude, tube, snake, pipe

The question was about how to script the creation of extra polygons to regions of a bent tube mesh only where the bending radius was tight, so as not to have too many total polygons. My example script was a bent tube and there may have been a GIF animation included in the question.

Is there any way that I can find questions that were deleted by the Community bot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have six deleted questions. Five you deleted, and one (probably the one you are looking for) was deleted by the community bot.

Here you go: [How to make these “orbit tubes” with fewer shapes via script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/63037/2217)

In case you wanted to see your other deleted answers:

- [How to draw or illustrate object's paths in space along with cycles rendering?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45045)
- [Is Blender simply the wrong tool to make this kind of 3D representation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/68146)
- [best source of info on how to navigate within blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34967)
- [3D viewport rendered from this script still unstable](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35475)
- [Higher math functions on generated coordinates to control cycles material nodes - Options?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67681)

---

You can always *see* your posts, OPs don't need 10k rep and the "View deleted posts" privilege to see your own posts. You do however need a link, it will not show up in your list of questions.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you for your time tracking all these down! Yes that's the one, and this/these will save me time remembering what I'd done and getting back up to speed again.

Answer (score 3):

As a regular user, no.

Users with [access to moderator tools](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) can only see [deleted questions within at most 30 days](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days), or search [their own deleted posts with `deleted:1` search operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3A1). It's still possible for them... to traverse each question posted in 2016 (from ID [44022](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44022) to [70222](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70222)) manually.

For users without that privilege, they can only see their own questions/answers deleted within 60 days.

Moderators might be able to help you since they can search for any deleted posts.

Comment: @uhoh oops, bad copy-paste. But, yes, if it's your own deleted posts, then you can use `deleted:1` after getting that privilege.

Comment: oh! From comments below [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1121/12102) you can see that this has been mentioned to me earlier, but I thought something like an SQL script was necessary. Now I understand that one can simply type `deleted:1` in the search bar in any site where one has sufficient privileges. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me!